# how to make right side bar in a grid layout?

Tags: css, css-grid

Here is my code:

```css
html,body {
    height:100%;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
   }
   .wrapper {
     display: grid;
     padding:0px;
     margin:5px;
     grid-gap: 5px;
     grid-template-columns: 10fr 10fr 0.5fr 1fr;
     grid-template-rows: 0.5fr 10fr 1fr;
     border: 1px solid blue;
     height: calc(100vh - 11px);
     width:calc(100vw-11px);
   }

   .box {
     font-family: arial;
     border: 1px solid black;
   }

   .a {
     grid-column: 1 / span 2;
   }

   .b {
     grid-column: 4;
     grid-row: 1 / span 3;
   }

   .c {
     grid-column: 1 /span 2;
     grid-row: 2;
   }

   .d {
     grid-column: 1;
     grid-row: 3;
   }

   .e {
     grid-column: 2;
     grid-row: 3;
   }
   .f {
     grid-column: 3;
     grid-row: 1 / span 3;
   }
```

```html
<link href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box a">A</div>
    <div class="box b">B</div>
    <div class="box f">F</div>
    <div class="box c">C</div>
    <div class="box d">D</div>
    <div class="box e">E</div>
</div>
```

How can I make the div "b" to be a sidebar?
That means when a user clicks on div "F", the div "B" disappear, the other divs expand to take up the new space, when the user clicks on div "F" again, the div "B" appears again, the other divs shrink to the original size.

It is because I have tried to set div "B" to 0fr, however, the div "B" did not minimize and the other divs did not expand.

The div "F" is the room for a button/tag to trigger the sidebar, it can be removed when the button/tag can reside in div "B".

I can accept a solution that can output the same layout and the right sidebar without using a grid layout.

Because of w3.css has set the box-sizing to "border-box", the dimension calculation has to be careful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Well before you add some extra info check this [link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)